# what is the difference between "transactions per second" with "requests per second" in performance tests?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

In some books there are these two statements but i can't get the difference between these two?
(transactions per second is named as "**system throughput**" also.)

Answer (score 1):

Why you're asking us and not the these "some books" authors?

Given you have [jmeter tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jmeter) here is JMeter-specific answer:

1. Transaction is equivalent for the [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) (or if you're grouping several Samplers together via [Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller) - the cumulative throughput of all Samplers under the Transaction Controller)

   Basically how many Samplers were executed during 1 second time frame.

   Can be visualized using i.e. [Transactions per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond/) chart
2. Requests per second is nearly the same metric, however in certain cases the number of requests per second can be higher than the number of transactions per second, for example:

   - when [HTTP Request Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) is downloading embedded resources, one "transaction" causes multiple "requests"
   - when script developer uses i.e. [Parallel Controller](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-controller) to simulate AJAX requests, the same network footprint - one "transaction", multiple "requests"

   These "requests per second" can be visualized using i.e. [Server Hits Per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HitsPerSecond/) chart

Answer (score 1):

Personal understanding:

The number of requests per second is how many requests can be issued by the client per second, and the number of transactions per second is how many requests from the client can be processed by the server per second. In theory, the number of requests per second should be equal to the number of transactions per second, but as the number of requests increases Increase the response time, and the number of requests per second is greater than or equal to the number of transactions per second.